# Relative redirect in Django

Tags: python, django, http, redirect

The url config of my app currently looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns("myapp.views",
    (r"^$", redirect_to, {"url": "main/"}),
    (r"^(?P<title>.+)/$", "article"),
    ...
)
```

This works fine when the app’s urls are used without prefix.

Now, i want to include my app’s urls into a project’s url config with a prefix; like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
    (r"^myapp/", include("myapp.urls")),
)
```

But then `http://myserver.org/myapp/` isn’t redirected to `http://myserver.org/myapp/main/`, but to `http://myserver.org/main/`.

I think I understand how it works: The project’s url patterns get `"myapp/"`. This matches the prefix, which is stripped away, leaving `""`, which is passed to the app’s patterns. The app is agnostic about the stripping and just redirects to `main/`, <del>which Django interprets as `/main/`</del>which doesn’t work for deeper nested urls (see edit below).

How to tell Django to redirect to a URL relative to the app’s prefix?

---

## Edit: Mistake!

Aah! Above code works fine, but my browser cached the permanent redirect to the previous url, which was `"/main/"`. I cleared my cache and my new url `"main/"` (which is now now temporary to prevent caching) Works just fine. Sorry!

But I realized that a answer would be helpful when I want to go to a url relative to the app’s root from a deeper nesting: `"relative/"` may work for `http://myserver.org/myapp/foo/`, but not for `http://myserver.org/myapp/foo/bar/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django 1.4 you will be able to use the function [`reverse_lazy()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-lazy):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
urlpatterns = patterns("myapp.views",
    (r"^$", redirect_to, {"url": reverse_lazy("myapp_title")}),
    (r"^(?P<title>.+)/$", "article", name="myapp_title"),
    ...
)
```

`reverse_lazy()` resolves to the URL which was given the same string as "name" parameter that is provided as an argument to `reverse_lazy()`.

If you are working with an earlier version, that you will have to specify the full path, which, of course, violates the DRY principle:

```
(r"^$", redirect_to, {"url": "myapp/title/"}),
```

Comment: So I’ll just upgrade to the dev version, as it’s a hobby program. Could you please check my edit? Is everything i assumed there right? ^^

Comment: umm, wait a second: how does `reverse_lazy` resolve to `/myapp/title/`? What if I want to redirect to e.g. `/myapp/main/` (Which i want, I got it wrong -.-)?

Comment: @flying sheep, you need to assing `name` parameter to URL you want to redirect to. For example `name="myapp_main"`. Then you do reverse_lazy("myapp_main") to get this URL. I did a little edit to clear things up :) You can redirect this way to any app from any place.

Comment: ah, ok, now it is clear enough, i think. so `reverse` and `reverse_lazy` give me the absolute url of any url pattern? but don’t they need arguments then in irder to know what url was matched? like `(r"^$", redirect_to, {"url": reverse_lazy("myapp_title", args=("main",))}),`

Comment: @flying sheep only if your URL's have arguments, like `/users/(\d+)`

Comment: umm, it has one: `(?P<title>.+)` that’s a keyword argument called “title”.